# perl curl code equivalent for -d -u

Tags: perl, curl

how can the below curl code from the command prompt curl be represented in the perl WWW:Curl ?

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_test_a02zSeLS9cMPlJvu2GkWgSDB: \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=sgd \
   -d description="Example charge" \
   -d source=tok_2s0QJK6exWUdbSGZb4SpAKep
```

## perl

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges');

# A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;
```

Comment: I don't see why people use WWW::Curl::Easy. I take that it's fast, but [it's not that much faster](http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/169) than HTTP::Tiny really, and apparently it's really not that _easy_.

Comment: When translating `curl` command line options, you would usually first refer to the manpage. If you find that tedious, try [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+https%3A%2F%2Fapi.stripe.com%2Fv1%2Fcharges+%5C++++-u+sk_test_a02zSeLS9cMPlJvu2GkWgSDB%3A+%5C++++-d+amount%3D1000+%5C++++-d+currency%3Dsgd+%5C++++-d+description%3D%22Example+charge%22+%5C++++-d+source%3Dtok_2s0QJK6exWUdbSGZb4SpAKep). Now you know what `-d` and `-u` do. Refer to https://curl.haxx.se/ to learn what the internal representation of those options is to use them with the Perl bindings.

Comment: ["This is not an ::Easy module in the sense normally used on CPAN."](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl#WWW::Curl::Easy)

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in the examples [here](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.17/lib/WWW/Curl.pm),

```
use WWW::Curl::Form;
my $curlf = WWW::Curl::Form->new;
$curlf->formadd("amount", "1000");
$curlf->formadd("currency", "sgd");
$curlf->formadd("description", "Example charge");
$curlf->formadd("source", "tok_2s0QJK6exWUdbSGZb4SpAKep");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $curlf);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD,"sk_test_a02zSeLS9cMPlJvu2GkWgSDB:");
```